# Running a python script for django via cron

Tags: linux, django, ubuntu, cron

I have a python script that connects to an external host, fetches some data, and populates a Django database with the data. The python script that populates the database uses these lines to setup the django environment:

```
path = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..'))
sys.path.append(path)
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)
```

Then I have a shell script that actually runs the python script:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/django/project_dir/
cd ~/project_dir/scripts/
~/virtualenv/bin/python my_script.py
```

And then my cron config, which is placed in /etc/cron.d/

```
0 1 * * * django ~/project_dir/scripts/my_script.sh > /var/log/django_cron.log
```

Note that the django project has it's own user and virtual environment.

The shell script runs fine when I am logged in as the django user. But the cron won't run! I get no errors in the log file. I'm sure it's something very simple, but I just don't see it...

Comment: Is anything showing up in `/var/log/cron` ?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a managment command ?

Comment: I get entries in the cron log that the cronjob was run at the specified time, so no problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was actually that I have an environment variable to tell django if it is running in development or production. Crontab doesn't execute the .bashrc file where I export this variable so that had to be added to my shell script:

```
export FLAVOR=live
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/django/project_dir/
cd ~/project_dir/scripts/
~/virtualenv/bin/python my_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind.  I don't think `cron` will make the tilde substitution you expect -- perhaps I'm wrong, but try specifying the full path (i.e. /home/myuser/project_dir/...) in your cron entry as well as your scripts.

Also, what's the "django" in your cron entry?  Is it the name of your script or is that a typo?  Finally, to log possible errors from the execution of your script, try:

```
0 1 * * * /home/myuser/project/script.sh > /var/log/django_cron.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Actually, now I have changed the setup so I do 'crontab -e' as the django user, and include the line you demonstrated. That's probably the proper way to do this.